# S3サーバーからEC2サーバーにファイルをダウンロードしたい。

Tags: php, aws, laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

laravelで開発しております。

初歩的な質問かと思いますが、S3サーバーからEC2サーバーへはどのようにしてファイルをダウンロードするのでしょうか。
こちらバイト配列としてダウンロードできるのでしょうか。

S3サーバーからファイルを取得して、末尾にバイト配列を結合して、再びS3サーバーにファイルを上書き保存することを考えております。

よろしくお願い致します。

4/18 追記になります。

S3サーバーからEC2サーバーへのファイル取得ですが、下記のようなコードで対応いたしました。

```
class Media extends Model
{
    public function getPreSignedUrl($minutes)
    {
        $url = \Storage::disk('s3')
            ->temporaryUrl(
                $this->file_name,
                Carbon::now()->addMinute($minutes));
        return $url;
    }
}

class MediaController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadSplit(Request $request, Media $media)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        
        $content = Storage::disk('s3')->get( $media->getPreSignedUrl(10) );
        
        if( isset( $content ) )
        {
            return [
                'message' => 'ok',
            ];
        }
        
        return [
            'message' => 'ng',
        ];
    }
}
```

「$content」を使用してバイナリ操作を行おうとしたのですが、途中から

```
League\\Flysystem\\FileNotFoundException(code: 0): File not found at path:
```

といったエラーが出るようになりました。
エラー文の前後にはS3サーバーのファイルダウンロードURLがついております。

こちら一時的なURLの取得ではいけないのでしょうか。
また、取得した「$content」をバイナリファイルとして扱うことは出来るのでしょうか。

初歩的な質問かと思いますがよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 参考サイト[Amazon EC2でのAmazonS3の使用](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonS3.html) [AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/sdk-for-php/)

Answer (score 3):

はい、LaravelでもS3のデータをローデータのまま読み書きすることができます。

AWS SDK for PHPを利用する方法でももちろん可能ですが、Laravelに備わっているFile Storage機能を利用するとローカルストレージの読み書きと同様の方法で操作できるため手軽です。

- [公式ドキュメント（英語）](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem)
- [日本語訳](https://readouble.com/laravel/8.x/ja/filesystem.html)

詳細はドキュメントをご確認頂ければと思いますが、おおまかには

- EC2にS3へのアクセス権を付与

  - `.env` にS3にアクセス可能な `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` と `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` を設定するか、あるいはEC2にS3アクセス可能なロールをアタッチする
- Composerで必要なパッケージを追加

  - `composer require "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0"`
- S3のインスタンスを取得して読み書き

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$content = Storage::disk('s3')->get('path/to/file');
Storage::disk('s3')->put('path/to/file', $content);
```

というような流れで利用します。

なお、もしストレージにS3しか利用しないということであれば `.env` の `FILESYSTEM_DRIVER` を `s3` にしておけば `disk('s3')` の指定は省略できます。

`s3` というディスクの定義については `config/filesystem.php` にあり、こちらは自由に設定できるので `s3-primary` `s3-secondary` などを追加して複数のディスクを行き来したりすることもできます。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
頂いた情報からS3サーバーからEC2サーバーにファイルを取得するように対応してみました。
しかし、途中からエラーが出てくるようになってしまいました。
こちら詳しくは質問文に追記いたしました。
こちらどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: `Storage::disk('s3')->get()` は引数にS3のパスを指定して利用するものですが、記載頂いたコードでは `Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl()` が返したURLを指定しているようです。

`temporaryurl()` が返す `Pre-Signed URL` は期間を限定してファイルダウンロードを可能にするURLで、これはパスとは異なるため、指定されたパスにファイルが存在しないということで `File not found at path` と言われているのではないかなと思います。

`Pre-Signed URL` をあえて利用している理由はありますでしょうか？ユーザに直接ダウンロードさせる際などに便利ですが、サーバサイドで完結する処理で利用するケースはあまりないかもしれません。

Comment: URLは毎回一時URLで対応しておりましたが、

 \Storage::disk('s3')->url( $this->file_name );

に変更しました。
しかし同じエラーが出ており、直接ブラウザで見た際もエラーが出ております。S3サーバーにファイルがあるのは確認しております。